# Big Gap between Header and Text in IE7

Tags: css

This is a very lame question, but I have struggled with it far too long and decided to admit the truth and go for help.

I have a series of pages on a new site that are proving problematic with the text hanging way down from the header. This only happens in IE7. It works properly in FF, Safari and IE8 - I don't even want to talk about IE6. There is something "pushing" or "holding" it down and I can't get it to come back up.

You can see the page [here](http://www.familyeyecareofapex.com/contacts)

I would appreciate some guidance on how to get it to position properly like this page does [here](http://www.familyeyecareofapex.com/cataracts).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add something like this to your CSS:

```
#contacts #nav {
  float:right;
  width:415px;
}
```

I compared the two pages, and the cataracts page has some CSS that floats `#cataracts #nav` to the right. After downloading the page and making the change, I tested it in IE7, and it works fine.